# starting gnome-terminal results in "Error constructing proxy..."

Tags: archlinux, gnome-terminal

Running `gnome-terminal` gives me

```
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling
StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

Output of `localectl`:

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: dvorak
      X11 Layout: dvorak
       X11 Model: pc105
```

What may be the cause of this error? It's mentioned [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ) but I'm not running it via sudo or root...

---

Running `sudo gnome-terminal` works correctly suprisingly enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked after I installed `gnome-session`, and running `gnome-session`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to kill my DE (?) - a big error screen appears with "**Oh no! Something has gone wrong.** A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again."

Answer (score 3):

[This forum thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/oh-no-something-has-gone-wrong-on-restart-4175510641/) made me find out, that you have to install whole gnome for it to work `pacman -S gnome` (instead of trying standalone `pacman -S gnome-terminal` or in my case `pacman -S gnome-session`).

---

An alternative solution would be to use `dbus-launch gnome-terminal` to start the terminal - as taken from [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=242220).

Answer (score 0):

Using `journalctl -f` reveals the following warning when starting `gnome-terminal`:

```
Nov 15 13:58:55 xxx systemd[1318]: xdg-desktop-portal.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Safe to assume the app uses xdg-desktop-portal which times out:

```
$ systemctl --user status xdg-desktop-portal
× xdg-desktop-portal.service - Portal service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/xdg-desktop-portal.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2023-11-15 13:58:55 CET; 3min 7s ago
    Process: 892978 ExecStart=/usr/lib/xdg-desktop-portal (code=killed, signal=TERM)
   Main PID: 892978 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
        CPU: 19ms

Nov 15 13:57:25 xxx systemd[1318]: Starting Portal service...
Nov 15 13:58:15 xxx xdg-desktop-por[892978]: Failed to create settings proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gnome: Timeout was reached
Nov 15 13:58:40 xxx xdg-desktop-por[892978]: Failed to create file chooser proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gnome: Timeout was reached
Nov 15 13:58:40 xxx xdg-desktop-por[892978]: No skeleton to export
Nov 15 13:58:55 xxx systemd[1318]: xdg-desktop-portal.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Nov 15 13:58:55 xxx systemd[1318]: xdg-desktop-portal.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Nov 15 13:58:55 xxx systemd[1318]: Failed to start Portal service.
```

`xdg-desktop-portal` seems to fail to start a service called "org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gnome". With enough inspiration you can find it, but the failure message does not say much:

```
$ pacman -Ss portal | grep gnome
extra/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome 45.0-1 (gnome) [installed]

$ systemctl --user status xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
○ xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service - Portal service (GNOME implementation)
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
Nov 15 18:56:46 xxx systemd[1318]: Dependency failed for Portal service (GNOME implementation).
Nov 15 18:56:46 xxx systemd[1318]: xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service: Job xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

Searching for "Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gnome: Timeout was reached" I found https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/issues/986 where some workarounds are suggested, pick something that works for you:

- Replace the `dbus` reference implementation with `dbus-broker`
- Uninstall xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
- Disable xdg-desktop-portal-gnome for your account by masking it: `systemctl --user mask xdg-desktop-portal-gnome --now`

Answer (score 0):

For those of you looking at this in Nov 2023, I had a similar issue where the terminal would not start.  I finally found the issue by running `journalctl -f` in one xterm while attempting to start the gnome-terminal.  The journal immediately printed out a message that non-UTF-8 was not supported.

I had set "LC_ALL" to "C" in my `.bashrc` to ensure a uniform sort order that worked the way I'm used to and had not rebooted for some time after that.  Removing the export statement from .bashrc fixed the issue.